# Local SQL Server 2008 Express data upload to Web based SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, consolidation

Over the next few months, we need to consider the best technology/technique for periodically uploading SQL Server 2008 Express data that is held on a local network up to a Web based SQL Server 2008 server.

The idea is to allow us to consolidate the data in 20 distributed (local) SQL Server Express 2008 apps in use throughout the country into a single database for reporting purposes (SSRS).

The database in each location is using a WinForms/WPF app and I would be looking for the local administrator to click a button in the app once a week/month to upload the latest data to the Web based server.

So, my question is, what technologies/techniques are popular, and what ones should be avoided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If [SQL Server Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198.aspx) isn't what you're looking for, be sure to check out the [Microsoft Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/default.aspx).

Using [SQL Server's merge replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152761.aspx), multiple databases can be combined. With the Sync Framework you can integrate syncing into your own application. This allows your administrator to push the button to upload all data.

I'd avoid creating sync scripts, because they can become very complex. Since you're combining data, comparing by primary key also isn't an option. There are tools to do this, like [SQL Delta](http://www.sqldelta.com/), but it will be very prone to human errors (eg. overwriting/deleting exiting data).

Comment: Hi Ronald, many thanks for your answer. I remember briefly looking at the Sync Framework a few years ago. I've had a quick look just now and it seems that version 2 might be what I'm looking for. Thanks again....